# Another word for "Compete with" in the context of Languages

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Scientists predict that Language X will compete with English in global usage.

Another expression or word instead of "compete with" in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [vie](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vie)?

> **vie,** verb (used without object), vied, vying.
>
> 1. to strive in competition or rivalry with another; contend for superiority

A phrase that is often used in situations like this is **vie for dominance** ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vie%20for%20dominance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvie%20for%20dominance%3B%2Cc0)). You could say:

> Scientists predict that Language X will vie for dominance with English in terms of global usage.

Comment: So, "Scientists predict that Language X and English will vie for global usage"?

Comment: @Hiro: No, you would have to tweak it slightly. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about **rival**?

> Having the same pretensions or claims: competing

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rival)

> Transitive verb
>
> 1 : to be in competition with